# Where is the Azure Media Service Region property?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, azure-media-services

The most simplest thing I thought... but no where to be found... When I'm creating throuh the portal a new media service I can choose a region for the new service, a storage account (with a different region (..question for another day)) and the rest for the properties.

However, when I connect with the SDK I got a CloudMediaContext. I can find any property for channels and live-streams/programs. However, where can I find the region for this Media Service Account? Is this coupled to another storage account (and why can I choose another region), or any other class or is this via another way coupled?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to find the information about Media Service account using SDK. Correct?

Comment: @GauravMantri Correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two things going on here:

1. **Control Plane**: Control plane deals with the management of service. It includes things like creation of service, fetching service details, key regeneration etc.
2. **Data Plane**: Data plane deals with the data in the service. So for media services, data plane deals with managing assets, locators etc.

Azure Media Service SDK deals with data plane only. You give it an account name and key and using that it gives you `CloudMediaContext` and you use that to manage data in your service.

In order to view the properties of the service itself (like the region), you would need to use [`Azure Resource Manager (ARM) SDK`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net) which is a wrapper over `Azure Resource Manager API` and not the Media Service SDK. This ARM SDK has support for Media Services.

Comment: that explains a lot! Didn't know that. thnx!